# Sitecore Can Publish Home But Not Other Content Tree

Tags: sitecore, publishing

I have a setup with one authoring site and two remote publishing sites.

If I publish from the /Home/ content tree from authoring that is reflected in all remote targets.

If I publish from any other content tree, say /Quotations/, that is not reflected in any of the remote targets. It is, however, reflected on the authoring machine's "Internet" site so the changes are being published locally.

The log file on the authoring site says that the publish of the Quotations content tree worked correctly and that N number of items were published (varies depending on how much I change and/or if I do a full or incremental publish but N is about what I expect it to be).

I'm feeling I've missed something in configuration but not sure where to look.

Many thanks!

rjsjr

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Are the templates and other items needed on the remote targets there to properly store the content?  If "Quotations" is using different templates that aren't published onto the remote target then you may be publishing empty content items.
- Are the remote targets configured within Sitecore's config files to be the proper databases to be pushing the content?

---

Time for another approach, could we isolate the problem to being one of the following:

- DB server. This would be taking the database for the remote target and running it on another web server to ensure that the DB is doing everything correctly in terms of serving up the data.
- Web server. This would be taking the web server that hosts the remote target and pointing it at another server to see that there isn't anything wrong with the web server like a misconfiguration in IIS or something like that.
- Connectivity between the two.  This is what is left if the DB works with another web server and the web server works with another DB server as each part can be eliminated as the problem being solely in one area.

Or do we know it is that last one that is the ugliest one to try to debug?

---

Are Home and Quotations siblings of each other?  If not, then there may be something above Quotations that is the source of the problem.

---

That I don't know.  I'd be tempted to ask this on the [Sitecore forms on their site](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum.aspx?) if you are certified in Sitecore you should be able to access it.

Comment: Published templates completely and the templates went over (made minor changes to make sure)

Comment: More complete text since I hit "Enter" inadvertently above..

* Published templates completely and the templates went over (made minor changes to make sure)
* Tried to publish Quotations and it still didn't work
* I modified the targets in the config file, specifically the connection strings to be both valid and invalid. Invalid strings throw exceptions, valid strings show that the publish process succeeded but no changes are visible.
* Flailing about.

Comment: I took the _master and _web databases and copied them from my authoring system to one remote target. Once I brought the site up everything looked correct. Published a page in the Home tree from Authoring to remote and it worked great. Published a change in the Quotations tree and it failed. Based on Home working I think the DB is properly configured... I'm obviously missing *something*.

Comment: Yes... Home and Quotations are siblings.

Comment: Created new site, copied authoring databases, modified Quotations, published, no changes seen on new site. Log files say...3/25/2011 3:26:25 PM (IN): 3/25/2011 3:26:25 PM (IN): Staging on server failover started
3/25/2011 3:26:25 PM (IN): ======================================================================
3/25/2011 3:26:31 PM (IN): Full cache cleared on failover
3/25/2011 3:26:31 PM (IN): Staging on server failover finished
3/25/2011 4:02:28 PM (IN): Staging server found: failover
3/25/2011 4:02:28 PM (IN): SourceDatabase: master
3/25/2011 4:02:28 PM (IN): TargetDatabase: failover

Comment: And another note - this was working prior to the installation of the OMS and Web Forms For Marketers modules. Are there known incompatibilities with those?